# Seaborn: Plotting Two bar graphs and two line graphs on the same

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is an example of my data set where the x label is monthly but y values are bi weekly:

```
    month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    temp_1 = [35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 100, 85, 65, 45, 35, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 100, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85,]
    temp_2 = [30, 35, 65, 55, 70, 85, 65, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75,  65, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75,  65,]
    kw_1 = [5, 23, 5 , 6, 6, 10, 3, 0 , 1, 4, 5, 23, 5 , 6, 3, 1, 6, 10, 3, 0, 0 , 1, 4, 8]
    kw_2 = [6, 6, 10, 3, 0 , 1, 4, 6, 10, 3, 0,  6, 10, 3, 0, 5, 23, 5 , 6, 5, 23, 5 , 1, 25 ]


    # set peak
    peak_1 = max(kw_1)
    peak_index_1 = kw_1.index(peak_1)

    peak_2 = max(kw_2)
    peak_index_2 = kw_2.index(peak_2)
```

How can I plot this using seaborn to look similar to [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data provided differs from the desired output time series, but I have drawn the x-axis as a month, the left side as a bar graph stacked in KW and the right side as a line graph with temperature as a line graph.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']*2
temp_1 = [35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 100, 85, 65, 45, 35, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 100, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85,]
temp_2 = [30, 35, 65, 55, 70, 85, 65, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75,  65, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75, 85, 85, 75, 65, 75,  65,]
kw_1 = [5, 23, 5 , 6, 6, 10, 3, 0 , 1, 4, 5, 23, 5 , 6, 3, 1, 6, 10, 3, 0, 0 , 1, 4, 8]
kw_2 = [6, 6, 10, 3, 0 , 1, 4, 6, 10, 3, 0,  6, 10, 3, 0, 5, 23, 5 , 6, 5, 23, 5 , 1, 25 ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month':month,'kw_1':kw_1,'kw_2':kw_2})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month':month,'temp_1':temp_1,'temp_2':temp_2})

df1 = df1.groupby('month', sort=False).sum().reset_index()
df2 = df2.groupby('month', sort=False).sum().reset_index()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

sns.set()
df1.set_index('month').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, grid=False, legend=False, ax=ax1)
# sns.barplot(data=df1, x='month', y=['kw_1','kw_2'], alpha=0.5, ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=df2, marker='o', sort = False, legend='auto', ax=ax2)

handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles1, labels1 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(handles+handles1, labels+labels1, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! In the screenshot, they are displaying the peak kw. How can I display that in the chart and legend?

Comment: I updated the code to include the peak index of kw_1 and kw_2

Comment: I actually got this error when tried running your code:
  ```
    sns.lineplot(data=df2, marker='o', sort=False, legend='auto', ax=ax2)
  File "ackages\seaborn\relational.py", line 1078, in lineplot
    sort=sort, err_style=err_style, err_kws=err_kws, legend=legend,
  File "te-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 663, in __init__
    x, y, hue, size, style, units, data
  File "C:\Applications\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 64, in establish_variables
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: A wide-form input must have only numeric values.```

Comment: From the content of the error, it seems that seaborn may be affected. The seaborn in my environment is 0.11.0.

Comment: ah yes, my version was 0.9.0 updating it resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you too.

Comment: Thanks again! 
Is there a way to hanle situations where the bar in the back has a lesser value? It normally would be hidden but I want it to be visible. 

I know changing stack to false is one way but I was hoping to find a solution with stacked chart.

Comment: `ax2.set_ylim(0,300)` In such a case, you can increase the maximum value of the line chart side to make the bar chart side look larger.

Comment: I think the transparency would be a better solution. Also, how can I make the peak bars red?